# Delete redundant emails in a conversation in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

[Outlook 2010 has the ability to delete redundant emails from a conversation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/use-conversation-clean-up-to-eliminate-redundant-messages-HA101867736.aspx). Redundant emails are those which were replied to and the reply contains their content already. Assuming the original mail does not contain attachments - it can be deleted.

The use for such an ability is to conserve disk space - maintaining the original message does not provide much benefit as is.

Is there a tool/macro that can be used to provide this functionality in Outlook 2007?