# Conversation clean up is greyed out

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I found [a question that mentions conversation cleanup](https://superuser.com/questions/290623/delete-redundant-emails-in-a-conversation-in-outlook-2007) in Outlook 2010.  Sounds like exactly what I'm looking for.

I'm trying to follow [the instructions from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/use-conversation-clean-up-to-eliminate-redundant-messages-HA101867736.aspx), but I can't seem to get the "Clean Up" option to become active.  It's greyed out.

My inbox is grouped into conversations.  I tried selecting the conversation heading.  I've tried selecting a message within the conversation.  I've tried selecting the Inbox folder.  Nothing seems to make the "Clean Up" option light up.  Am I missing something?

I am connected to an Exchange 2003 server, so is that potentially a problem?

**Update:**  [A video tutorial from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/showcase/details.aspx?uuid=9ba96443-dae0-4cfe-9861-e3f55266c189) shows "Clean Up Conversation" as a right-click option on the conversation.  I do not have that option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through [the following thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/6e26cc8f-8614-43cb-b293-036f0f71aca4/), and hovering over the "Clean Up" option revealed the following information.

[image: Clean Up Error]

> **This command is currently disabled.** This feature is not available because you are running in online mode and connected to Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 or earlier.

I'm connected to Exchange 2003 and using Online Mode, so that's the problem.

Comment: I use Exchange 2003 and Outlook 2010 and use "Clean up" to get rid of redundant messages in folders such as Inbox or Sent Items quite often. Difference is, I use "cached mode" rather than "online mode", which is specifically referred to in the error message you show here, so I think the mode is the problem, not the version.
Ask your administrator if it would be possible to use cached mode so you can use this very useful feature to reduce your mailbox size (what admin won't like the idea of users with smaller mailboxes?!)

Comment: @AdamV Our admins really discourage cached mode.  The home drives are networked, and the profiles are synced with a server, so caching the files would increase the network traffic.  The local filesystem is frozen, so that's not an option either.  Even if the files could be local, moving the mail out of the Exchange server removes some of the security management abilities from the admins.  Too bad this can't be done without cached mode.